# getNamedQuery throws 'Invalid Column name' on linux works fine on windows

Tags: linux, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am migrating a web application from Windows to Linux OS, in my app I have used getNamedQuery() to run few store procedures, although this worked fine on Windows, on Linux i get an exception 'Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name XXXXX1_155_0_.' error, Is anybody aware of any platform specifics am missing out ??

Answer (score 0):

Your `column name` in `DB` table and which specified in your `app` is not matching. Verify them.

Comment: Ok..in that case I would get the same error on Windows as well right?

Comment: You have another `DB` on linux, don't you.

Comment: I verified the column name in the store procedure as well as application (pojo class), they are all in synch. Plus the column name I get in the error 'XXXX1_155_0_' is random, the string '1_155_0_' is getting appended to my column name. I checked but could not find this column name anywhere in db or app code.

Answer (score 0):

Posting late.... I resolved this issue by removing getNamedQuery API with CallableStatement.. it seems using stored procedure with a composite id defined was creating a problem after migrating to Hibernate 3.6. Stored procedures not using a composite Id seem to work fine.

Not a standard fix... but it worked for time being.